# Clojure - storing maps into a list of maps on keys

Tags: list, clojure, set, maps

Say I have two maps in clojure.

```
(def map1 {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1})
(def map2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil})

(def listofmaps '({:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil}))
```

If :a value matches with any map in listofmaps and map1, then if map1 :d is not null, put :d value from map1 into the matching map in listofmaps.

Like, first we compare map1 and listofmaps - now if map1 (:a 1) matches with any maps in listofmaps (:a 1), if map1 (:d not null) replace (matching map in listofmaps with map1 :d value) and if map1 (:c not null) replace (matching map in listofmaps with map1 :c value)

```
    (def map1 {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1})
    (def listofmaps '({:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil}))
```

Then map2 (:a 1) matches with a map in listofmaps (:a 1) and :

```
    (def map2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil})
    (def listofmaps '({:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil}))
```

if map2 (:d not null) replace (matching map in listofmaps with map2 :d value) and if map2 (:c not null) replace (matching map in listofmaps with map2 :c value)

```
     output=> '({:a 1 :b 1 :c 3 :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil})
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by ":a value matches in list of maps"? Do you mean that there is a value for the :a key in the first map of the listofmaps?  Or that there is a value for the :a key in any of the maps in listofmaps? Or something else?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: There is a value for the :a key in any of the maps in listofmaps?

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what is meant by  in list of maps and map2, here is a reasonably common pattern of adding in missing values in priority order.

```
(let [map1 {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1}
      map2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil}
      list-of-maps [{:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil}]
      or-fn (fn [a b] (or a b))] 
 (->>
   list-of-maps
   (map #(merge-with or-fn % map1))
   (map #(merge-with or-fn % map2))))
({:a 1, :b 1, :c 3, :d 1} {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2, :d 1})
```

Comment: It should not output {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2, :d 1} as neither (map1 :a) or (map2 :a) matches with (the second map :a) in listofmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question to be

If the value of the `:a` key in the new map matches the value of the `:a` key in any map in `listofmaps`, then, for each such matched map, replace the values of the keys :c and :d in that matched map in `listofmaps` by a new value only if the corresponding new value is not null.

Assuming that, here is an answer.
If I did not understand the question correctly, please clarify and show your desired output.

```clj
user> (def map1 {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1})
#'user/map1
user> (def map2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d nil})
#'user/map2
user> (def listofmaps [{:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2 :d nil}])
#'user/listofmaps
user> (defn mapper [m ms]
        (mapv (fn [elem]
                (if (= (:a elem) (:a m))
                  (merge-with #(or %1 %2) (select-keys m [:c :d]) elem)
                  elem))
              maps))
#'user/mapper
user> (mapper map1 listofmaps)
[{:c nil, :d 1, :a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2, :d nil}]
user> (mapper map2 listofmaps)
[{:c 3, :d 1, :a 1, :b 1} {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2, :d nil}]
user>
```